# What does s=jω actually mean in terms of the complex plane and Laplace transforms?

Tags: complex-numbers, laplace-transform

I was trying to solve a problem on RC circuits. The current source was of the form $\cos (\omega t)$ which transforms in the manner of Laplace to $\frac{s}{s^2+\omega^2}$. I thought I’d use the complex reactance for the capacitor which is $1/j \omega C$ and so I should replace $s$ in the above term with $j \omega$. But that would make the denominator of the term infinite. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In general the complex variable s is equal to a+jw, where a is the exponential damping portion of the complex frequency. When s is equal to only jw, it means you are considering a small portion of the complex response related to only the imaginary axis in the s plane, which in this case would be a purely reactive circuit (i.e. no resitance).  This leads to the result that your current source would put out infinite current with no resistance is the circuit.

Comment: Even a purely reactive circuit has an impedance/reactance. How can there be infinite current if there is finite capacitance?

Comment: Well clearly there can't be. That's why the quantity here is actually undefined. What I meant to say was that considering your circuit with only a reactance (i.e. 1/jwC for the capacitor, instead of 1/sC as it should be) was improper.

Comment: I'm getting confused.
What I thought was that in phasor diagrams we represent inductance along the positive imaginary axis (jωL) and capacitance along the negative imaginary axis (1/jωC) because of the phase differences. And since both these reactances only exist along the imaginary axis, s=jω in this case.
Could you clarify?
(I get that this is a lot to do with electrical engineering as well but I wasn't sure which forum I should go with. If this is an issue I can post this in EE as well.)

Comment: so let's reconsider your problem statement a minute. As I read over your question again, it seems like maybe you're replacing the s in the current source's function with 1/jwC? Is that right?